# Arranging div elements using tables and floats

Tags: html, css

I have the following div elements that are generated randomly so I can't make changes to a single div element.Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/y638o46h/2/. Here is what I need http://prntscr.com/5i5vz3.

html

```
<div class="relatedposts">
<div class="relatedthumb">
 <img src="" >
    <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="relatedthumb">
 <img src="" >
     <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="relatedthumb">
 <img src="" >
     <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="relatedthumb">
 <img src="" >
     <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="relatedthumb">
 <img src="" >
     <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="relatedthumb">
 <img src="" >
    <h3 class="justin-cover">This one clearly has too many lines that do not fit</h3>
 </div>
```

css

```
 *{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;}

 .relatedposts {
 display:table; 
 width:1024px;font-size: 0;
 /* fix inline gap */
 margin: 0 auto;}

.relatedthumb {
 float: left;
  margin-left:5px;
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 }

.relatedthumb img {
 text-align:center;
 }

.justin-cover {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 500;
 /* height: 30%; */
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left:0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 padding: 10px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 }
```

Comment: check this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float_elements

Comment: Can't understand what you try to achieve.

Comment: Hi @turtle - in your proposed layout you have 1 large image and 4 smaller images, but in your code you have 6 images. Please can you clarify? Thanks.

Comment: The thing is all the images are randomly generated with the same class so I don't know how to make changes to a single element and I need to resize the the first div and rearrange the remaining divs accordingly

Comment: Ah, okay, I think I can work with that. Answer coming up...

Comment: @Rounin I did that to arrange the elements properly.But you're right to achieve what I need requires 5 images because the first one needs to take up the space for 2 images

Comment: @AlexChar I need to increase the size of the first image so that it takes up the space of 2 images and the remaining four arrange themselves as in the screenshot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To target the first div you can use [**:first-child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child):

```
/*This one target the first div with class relatedthumb that is child div of an element with class relatedposts */
.relatedposts div.relatedthumb:first-child
```

To target the img of the first div:

```
.relatedposts div.relatedthumb:first-child img
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like this, but the downfall is that you need a fixed height

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y638o46h/7/)

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.relatedposts {
    display:table; 
 width:1024px;
    height: 256px;
    font-size: 0;
    /* fix inline gap */
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.relatedthumb {
    float: left; 
 position: relative; 
    text-align: center;
    width: 23%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px 1%;
}
.relatedposts .relatedthumb:first-child{
    width: 48%;
    height: 520px;
}
.relatedthumb img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
     width: auto;
}
.justin-cover {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;    
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 padding: 10px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="relatedposts">     
      <div class="relatedthumb">
         <img src="http://placekitten.com/336/200" >
             <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
     </div>
      <div class="relatedthumb">
         <img src="http://placekitten.com/336/200" >
             <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
     </div>
      <div class="relatedthumb">
         <img src="http://placekitten.com/336/200" >
             <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
     </div>
   <div class="relatedthumb">
         <img src="http://placekitten.com/336/200" >
             <h3 class="justin-cover">Lets make this work</h3>
     </div>
   <div class="relatedthumb">
         <img src="http://placekitten.com/336/200" >
            <h3 class="justin-cover">This one clearly has too many lines that do not fit</h3>
     </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're looking for : [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8wo7fpco/)

HTML:

```
<section class="page">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="obj"></div>
        <div class="obj"></div>
        <div class="obj"></div>
        <div class="obj"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
*{box-sizing: border-box;}


body {
    margin:20px
}
.left, .obj {
    border: 2px solid gainsboro;
    margin:2px;
}
.container {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    margin:2px;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.obj {
    height: 146px;
    width: 146px;
    float: left;
}
```